# Usefulness of the commutator subgroup - understanding the proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Also let $C \le G$ be the commutator subgroup.
I'm trying to understand the statement:

If $C \le N$ then $G/N$ is abelian, and the proof is as follows :

> If $C \le N$, then : $$aNbN=abN=ab(b^{-1}a^{-1}ba)N=(abb^{-1}a^{-1})baN=baN=bNaN$$

Where did we use the property "$C\le N$" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $b^{-1}a^{-1}ba\in C\leq N$, we have $$N=(b^{-1}a^{-1}ba)N$$

Remark:
$C$, the commutator subgroup of $G$ is a subgroup of $G$ generated by all the commutator of $G$.
For $a,b\in G$, $[b,a]$ is a commutator of $b$ and $a$ hence, $b^{-1}a^{-1}ba=[b,a]\in C$.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is already a nice answer. I will try to intuitively explain what is going on.

When ever you have something non commutative, one thing you can always do is go modulo the commutativity relations. The commutator subgroup is precisely generated by these relations. Now clearly if you go modulo more relations it will still be commutative.

This process of going modulo the commutativity relations is called abelianisation. You might want to check out [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/abelianization).